# GDAL "Simple Tiling" (Or yet another - how do I tile question)

Tags: gdal, tiles, mapping

Before I start, if anyone considers this a duplicate, then that's fair enough, I'll not object, I do happen to think however that it's a question that I don't see a clear answer for either here or elsewhere.

What I need to do is to create a simple, flat set of tiles from a single large raster.

I'm aware that we have "gdal2tiles" in the os4gw toolset, but this insists on creating the simple features recommended folder structure which is not what I need to do.

I'm also aware that there are other tools (GDAL warp I think does it) that have the "Projection Window" option, allowing to extract only a given region, but for that to work I need to provide the geo co-ordinates on the command line, which means creating loops and increment things correctly, not a task that anyone working on windows really relishes :-)

I'm prepared to write my own tool if I have to, using either C and/or C# and the GDAL Libraries, but before I go down this route, I thought I'd ask here.

Put simply, is there a tool, or an option in the existing tools I may have missed that allows me to say:

**c:>tilethisimage size=256x256 bigmap.tif**

and end up with

**tile-0-0.tif**
**tile-1-0.tif**
**tile-2-0.tif**
**tile-3-0.tif**
**tile-4-0.tif**
.
.
.
.
**tile-0-20.tif**
**tile-1-20.tif**
**tile-2-20.tif**
**tile-3-20.tif**
**tile-4-20.tif**

Or similar, in the current directory, without the complication of having to sort through folders, figure out zoom levels or anything else?

All I need is the larger image cut into tiles of the requested size, and with the correct geo-spatial reference data embedded in them.  I don't need KML's, Virtual raster's, tab files, world files or anything else.

If it wasn't for the fact I needed to preserve the geo-spatial co-ordinate info and have those co-ordinates mapped correctly for the tile sizes, I would quite simply just use imagemagik to cut the image.

Comment: If you plan on going the C/C++ route this might be helpful: [gdalsplit - the opposite of gdal_merge](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2004-September/004135.html)

Comment: I think you could use http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html

Comment: You probably don't want to cut on geo coordinates anyway - subject to round-off error, and you can miss a line. Do the cutting in image space.

Comment: @mdsummer  your suggestion totally works, I really should have paid more attention to the various py scripts.  In general I tend to shy away from the py scripts on 64 bit windows, as python on WX64 is I find, very unstable.  If you want to write your suggestion up as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BradHards - cutting via pixel size is what I was looking for, hence why I suggested using imagemagik, which I would have done if I didn't need to preserve the geospatial info present in the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the "gdal_retile.py" script:

http://gdal.org/gdal_retile.html

:)